# WMS for Active Fire Data from NASA site - Can't connect

Tags: qgis, wms, modis, nasa

I am trying to connect to the WMS service of the Active Fire Data that NASA provides. This is the site: https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/web-services/#firms-wms where I get the links from. My procedure is: copy one of the example links

> http://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/wms-t/viirs/?TIME=2016-02-01&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=VIIRS_Hotspots&width=512&height=512&BBOX=-20037508.3427892480,-20037508.3427892480,20037508.3427892480,20037508.3427892480&SRS=EPSG:3857

and paste it into the WMS connection in QGIS. It just takes too long, and never actually load anything.I don't know if I just have to leave it the whole night loading, or there is something going on (something wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the right link to connect to the WMS:

https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/wms/c6/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GETCAPABILITIES

I'm able to connect, but the images are no displayed and it says that the Images are defect. So its definitely a server problem of the NASA-Server. You can contact them or maybe try again in awhile...

Comment: Although after a while I managed to connect to the link I posted in the question, the one you posted connected better (faster), but as you say, there might be a server problem. Well, I will have to keep downloading the shapefile every time. Thanks